# CSS expand dropdown to fill the remaining space in fixed width table cell

Tags: css

My table cell has fixed width and contains select list and one or two buttons in a row. Select should fill all the space before buttons. I solved this with div wrapper, but my boss doesn't allow me to use any additional divs because from his point of view each element must symbolize some program data. He alsow doesn't allow me to use flexboxes.

Here's the code of how it should look like

```css
 td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1px;
        min-width: 300px;
       }
    table {
          margin: 50px;
          background-color: green;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          }
    button {
           padding: 1px;
           float:right;
           }
    select {
            width: 100%;
           }
    #wrap {
           overflow:hidden;
           }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<button>+</button>
<div id="wrap">
<select>
 <option value>ttttttttt</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can do this without additional elements or non-cross-browser solutions like flexboxes?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Since you can't use flexboxes, I assume you need to support older versions of Internet Explorer.  (So CSS3 `calc()` can't help you.)  In that case, I don't think there's a solution without using additional elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this option with help of inner table and without any additional wrappers.  https://jsfiddle.net/xkLaq47m/

/*---CSS---*/

```
 td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1px;
        min-width: 300px;
       }
    table {
          margin: 50px;
          background-color: green;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          }
    .inner-table{
      margin: 0;      
    }
    .inner-table__button-cell{
      min-width: 15px;
    }
    button {
           padding: 1px;
           float:right;
           }
    select {
            width: 100%;
           }


  /*---HTML---*/  

<table>
<tbody>  
<tr>
  <td>
  <table class="inner-table">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>
<select>
 <option value="">ttttttttt</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td class="inner-table__button-cell">
        <button>+</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```